# Save an image created from php to a destination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, image-uploading

i have this piece of code block.

```
<?php

    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = $_POST['src'];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

//save it and json encode here

?>
```

What i want is `php` creating the image using `src` and then saving it to a folder with a  `name.jpeg` and `json_encode` it to jquery. How do i do this ?

Comment: where you have `null` in `imagejpeg` is where you put the destination/filename

Comment: Put the destination path in your second argument of [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php#refsect1-function.imagejpeg-parameters)

Comment: Also what you want to json_encode? The source of image URL?

Answer (score 1):

that [Imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php#refsect1-function.imagejpeg-parameters) 2nd parameter worked

```
imagejpeg($dst_r,$mydestinationfolder,$jpeg_quality);

json_encode(array("dest"=>$mydestinationfolder));
```

This worked thanks contributors.

Comment: Remember your `$mydestinationfolder` may be a directory path instead of URL.